# Website sides not fitting on iPad

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, html

We are building a new section of our website and the sides of our website are not fitting correctly on iOS. We are using extensive Jquery. My developers are not able to fit the website correctly on the iPad and iPhone.

I will greatly appreciate your help on how to optimize the page so that it displays correctly. [image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to inform the mobile device of the total width of your website, with the 'viewport' meta tag.
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html